# Why are the elements in the list not sorted properly after filtering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, menu

I wrote a filtering function in a menu that I created, but other than "All menu" there is corruption. In other words, it puts one element of a menu with 2 elements to the far right and the other to the left. But I want them to stand side by side. How can I do that? I think I made a mistake in the css codes, but I couldn't find where I made a mistake.

- https://resimlink.com/4Hn3R5cvoW
- https://resimlink.com/hUEenxCzSgD

```js
const liItem = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
const imgItem = document.querySelectorAll('.product img');


liItem.forEach(li => {
    li.onclick = function(){
    //active
    liItem.forEach(li => {
        li.className = '';
    })
    li.className = 'active';
    

    //Filter
    // console.log(li.textContent);

    const value = li.textContent;
    imgItem.forEach(img => {
        img.style.display = 'none';
        console.log(img.getAttribute('data-filter'));
        if (img.getAttribute('data-filter') == value.toLowerCase() || value == 'All Menu'){
            img.style.display = 'block';
        }
    })  
    }
});
```

```css
body, h1, ul, li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
}


section{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

section h1{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}

ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul li{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;

}

ul li.active{
    background-color: rgb(73, 202, 73);
}

.product{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    flex-wrap: wrap ;
}

.product img{
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



/* body,h1,ul,li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #667d8e;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
section{
    width: 85%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
section h1{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}
ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.57);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul li.active{
    background-color: rgba(41, 255, 41, 0.897);
}
.product{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.product img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
} */
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Filter Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <section>
            <h1>Filter Image</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="active">All Menu</li>
                <li>Food</li>   
                <li>Car</li>
                <li>House</li>
                <li>Animal</li>
                <li>History</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="product">
                <img src="food_photos/food_1.jpeg" data-filter="food">
                <img src="food_photos/food_2.jpeg" data-filter="food">
                <img src="food_photos/food_3.jpeg" data-filter="car">
                <img src="food_photos/food_4.jpeg" data-filter="car">
                <img src="food_photos/food_5.jpeg" data-filter="house">
                <img src="food_photos/food_6.jpeg" data-filter="house">
                <img src="food_photos/food_1.jpeg" data-filter="animal">
                <img src="food_photos/food_2.jpeg" data-filter="animal">
                <img src="food_photos/food_3.jpeg" data-filter="history">
                <img src="food_photos/food_4.jpeg" data-filter="history">
                
            </div>


        </section>

        

        


        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please explain your expected output in detail.

Comment: That's what `justify-content: space-between;` does. Removing the property from the rule fixes the issue, it could introduce some other issues, though.

Comment: @NehaSoni OP has explained the current output: "_it puts one element of a menu with 2 elements to the far right and the other to the left_". And the goal: "_I want them to stand side by side_".

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I got that before. My meant was the expected UI refers to "stand-side-by-side.

Comment: @Mirza, as you said, `I want them to stand side by side`, just remove the `display`, `justify-content`, and `flex-wrap` properties from your `.product` style.

Comment: Thank you very much to each and every one of you for your help. justify-content: space-between; After removing this the attribute and for each img element to be at a distance of 10px from each other, add padding-left: 10px; After writing it, I got the result I wanted. I'm new yet. I'm trying to learn and understand CSS. Thanks all of you again!

Comment: @Teemu Hey There,
I removed it but I have a problem. How does one use CSS code to evenly distribute images among one another? 
<div class="product">
<img src="food_photos/car_2.webp" data-filter="car">
<img src="food_photos/house_1.jpeg" data-filter="house">
<img src="food_photos/house_2.webp" data-filter="house">
<img src="food_photos/animal_1.jpeg" data-filter="animal">
<img src="food_photos/animal_2.jpeg" data-filter="animal">
<img src="food_photos/historical_1.jpeg" data-filter="history">
<img src="food_photos/historical_2.jpeg" data-filter="history">
 </div>

Comment: Ah, I have succeeded. I apply the margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto styles, and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `product` contains the following rule which is creating the unexpected behaviour:

```css
justify-content: space-between;
```

Use this ruleset instead:

```css
.product{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share the latest version of my code with you. There is no problem with the whole menu option, but when I switch to other menus, I still have problems displaying it because there are few items in other menus. If there are enough images to not occupy the whole row, I want them to be sorted from the left. What should i do?

```
 - https://codepen.io/mirzasahin/pen/GRGbNmq
```

https://ibb.co/VWDxLQt
https://ibb.co/YPjfQP9 (PROBLEM)